# Shortest way to initialize a dictionary

Tags: f#

Is there a terser way to declare and initialize a dictionary in F#?

```
let grid = Map.empty
              .Add(0, true).Add(1, true).Add(2, true)
              .Add(3, true).Add(4, false).Add(5, true)
              .Add(6, true).Add(7, true).Add(8, true)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use:

```
[0, true
 1, false
 2, true]
|> Map.ofList
```

Comment: @ScottNimrod Yes, just use `;` as the delimiter: `[1, true; 2, false; 3, false]`, `,` is for creating tuples, `;` serves as list element delimiter.

Answer (score 3):

@CaringDev's answer is good, but there's yet another consideration.

The elements of the tuple have key/value relation, so for best clarity I use the following definition:

```
let (=>) x y = x,y
```

This lets me write a very readable, [*self-documented*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-documenting) code like this:

```
let myValue1 =
    Map [
        0 => true
        1 => false
        2 => false
    ]
```

Also, `let makeMap x = new Map<_,_>(x)` lets you write the code in another style, depending on your team's coding conventions:

```
let myValue2 =
    [
        0 => true
        1 => false
        2 => false
    ] |> makeMap
```